# Process one line at a time in a txt file, print out a file per processed line, perl

Tags: perl, hash, printing, fasta

I am able to generate a hash that contains something like the following:

```
    AAAA => AAAAAAAA 
    TTTT => TTTTTTTT 
    GGGG => GGGGGGGG 
    CCCC => CCCCCCCC
```

I have a text file that contains something like the following:

```
    AAAA    AAAA 
    GGGG 
    TTTT    TTTT    TTTT 
    CCCC    CCCC
```

I want to be able to open the text file, read each line, and search the contents of the line for matches to the keys in the hash. If there are matches, I want to print the corresponding values out in a file specific to that line in the text file. The output I am hopping to get for the first file would be something like:

```
    >AAAA 
    AAAAAAAA 
    >AAAA 
    AAAAAAAA
```

And the output for the second file would be:

```
    >GGGG 
    GGGGGGGG
```

I know there is a way to accomplish this, but I am at a loss. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you!

Here is my code so far. Note that I am setting up to only write to one file, but I need to write to as many files as there are lines in the text file previously mentioned (hundreds to thousands).

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl 
    use warnings; 
    use strict; 

    my $dir = ("Users/rob/Documents/Lamda");  
    open (INFILE, "<", "Users/rob/dnaclust/testscript.txt") or die $!; 
    open (OUTFILE, ">", "Users/rob/Codes/testscript.txt") or die $!; 

    my %hash = (); 

    my @ArrayOfFiles = glob "$dir/*";  

    print join("\n", @ArrayOfFiles), "\n"; 

    foreach my $file (@ArrayofFiles){ 
       open (my $sequence, $file) or die "can't open file: $!";
       while (my $line = <$sequence>) {
         if ($line !~/^>/){ 
             my $seq = $line; 
             $seq =~ s/\R//g;
             $seq =~ m/(CATCAT|TACTAC)([TAGC]{18})([TAGC]+)([TAGC]{18})(CATCAT|TACTAC)/;  
            $hash{$2} = $3;   
         }
       } 
    } 
    while (<INFILE>) { 
         chomp; 
         my @fields = split /\n/;
```

So this gives me access to each line at a time, but now I just need to match all elements in the line to the keys in the hash, and print out the values to a file.

Comment: You've summarized the steps you need to take nicely, that's farther than most people get. Now, which step are you having trouble with?

Comment: Use `split` to get the words on each line, loop over them and use the hash to get the corresponding strings.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the quick response. I am looking for help with setting up the hash search, and of most importance, keeping the search and print actions to one line at a time, moving down the txt file one line at a time. Every line in the txt file should produce a file with matches in the format described above. Any insights?

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: I can't comment it- the code is too long.

Comment: Should I edit my original post to include what I have so far to get the hash?

Comment: Throw all the code you've got so far into the question, that way, people can see how far you've got, and what exactly you're having trouble with

Comment: Do you know how to open a file? Do you know how to read a file line-by-line? Do you know how to check if a key exists in a hash? Do you know how to print the value corresponding to a particular key in a hash?

Comment: I just edited my question to include my code so far. Hope this helps everyone! Thanks for your patience. So far, this will open a file, read it one by one (the while loop, right guys?). In terms of checking if a key exists in a hash- I have an idea of how to do that, but only in a situation like a single element in an array and then printing out one file. I am not sure how to go line by line, and then make a file per line processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to do what you are asking for.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my %convert = (
  AAAA => 'AAAAAAAA',
  TTTT => 'TTTTTTTT',
  GGGG => 'GGGGGGGG',
  CCCC => 'CCCCCCCC',
);

while (<>) {
  my @tokens = split;
  open my $out, '>', "line_$..out" or die $!;
  foreach my $token (@tokens) {
    if (exists $convert{$token}) {
      print $out ">$token\n$convert{$token}\n";
    }
  }
}
```

You run it, passing in the name of the input file (I really don't like hard-coding filenames unnecessarily). You can easily adjust the name of the created output files by editing the call to `open()`.

Comment: That does the trick Dave! I am so very grateful for your help, truly. I knew there had to be a way to do this :) I am somewhat new to bioinformatics and coding. I couldn't do it without the support of the great community at Stack Overflow. Have a good day everyone.

Comment: If you're really grateful, then perhaps you could upvote or accept my answer.

Comment: I clicked the green check mark, but I don't think it let me upvote it. I might not have enough "reputation" or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go about it like this:

- Read in your file
- Loop through file line by line
- [Split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) anything separated by a space into an array
- Check if any of these match your hash key
- If they do print out key and value of hash

This doesn't tell you how to print each of these to their own files, but it should help you on your way. Maybe that's another question?

```
open my $infile, '<', 'in.txt' or die $!;

my %hash = (
    AAAA => 'AAAAAAAA', 
    TTTT => 'TTTTTTTT', 
    GGGG => 'GGGGGGGG', 
    CCCC => 'CCCCCCCC'
);

while(<$infile>){
    chomp;
    my @fields = split;
    if ($hash{$fields[0]}){
        foreach (@fields){
            print ">$fields[0]\n";
            print "$hash{$fields[0]}\n";
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

---

```
>AAAA
AAAAAAAA
>AAAA
AAAAAAAA

>GGGG
GGGGGGGG

>TTTT
TTTTTTTT
>TTTT
TTTTTTTT
>TTTT
TTTTTTTT

>CCCC
CCCCCCCC
>CCCC
CCCCCCCC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback fugu! This will be a good starting point. I just now need to figure out how to print not to just one file, but to a unique file per line in the text file. I fear that putting all elements from the text file into an array and then splitting them takes away the ability to process and print one line at a time. Regardless, one file is better than no file! Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! You you try making a count variable, that increments every line, and then incorporate that into an outfile name?

Comment: "a count variable, that increments every line" - you mean like `$.` :-)

Comment: @DaveCross - Didn't want to spoon feed!